# What will be the insert query depends on previous data in same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert a row if it's one specific column value is not still available. If available, i want to update that row. Otherwise it will insert normally. What should be the SQL query for this task?

For example:
id, Product_id, user_id, quantity are the table's attributes

Considering, 
[1, 450, 56, 2] is in table.

If i want to insert [2,450,56,3] then it will not create new row. It will update the previous row. Like [1,450,56,5].

Comment: What you’re looking for is typically called “upsert”; different DBMSs have different levels of support for this.

Comment: I am using MySQL

Comment: Please share us your query

Comment: INSERT INTO `carts`(`sId`, `product_id`, `picture`, `product_title`, `qty`, `unit_price`, `total_price`) VALUES (4566,456,'img-4556','Book',1,100,100) on duplicate key update qty=qty+1 , total_price=qty*unit_price

Comment: Which is the key based on which you want to check the uniqueness of the record i.e how do you want to determine if the record needs to be updated on inserted?

Comment: the keys are Product_Id and sId,

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by creating a unique constraint on the combination of `product_id` and `user_id` (or even a primary key if you don't have one on the table yet):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_product_user UNIQUE (product_id, user_id);
```

And then you can use the `on duplicate` clause in an `insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES (2, 450, 56, 3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + VALUES(quantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set product_id and user_id as the primary key or unique key on the table and then use INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. You can find more information about that [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

It would look something like:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (id, product_id, user_id, quantity) VALUES (2,450,56,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + 3;
```

Alternatively, you're going to have to write your own *merge* statement (MySql doesn't support merge, but you can fake it)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_updateValue`(IN prm_productid INT, IN prm_userid INT, IN prm_quantity INT)
BEGIN


-- Check that the case actually exists first.

DECLARE vExists INT;

SELECT COUNT(1) INTO vExists FROM YourTable WHERE product_id = prm_orderid AND user_id = prm_userid;

IF vCaseExists = 1 THEN

    UPDATE YourTable SET quantity = prm_quantity WHERE product_id = prm_orderid AND user_id = prm_userid;

ELSE 
    INSERT INTO YourTable (id, product_id, user_id, quantity) VALUES (2,450,56,3);
END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```